# Derivative in the case of conditional expectation

Tags: probability

How can I prove that:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \gamma}\mathrm E[Z,X>γ]= E[ Z\mid X=γ](-f_X (γ))$$ where $f_X (γ)$ is the density function of the random variable $X$.

It is a short question, I know, but I can't seem to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Try to show that $E[Z;X\gt\gamma]=\int\limits_\gamma^\infty E[Z\mid X=x]f_X(x)\mathrm dx$.

You might want to assume for simplicity that $(X,Z)$ has a density $f_{X,Z}$, to deduce that, conditionally on $X$, $Z$ has a conditional density $(f_{Z\mid X}(\ \mid x))_x$, and to use it to compute $E[Z;X\gt\gamma]$ for every $\gamma$.

Comment: I have been looking at your answer but this particular question still remains quite hard. How can I write $E[Z;X>γ]$ differently? Sorry if it's a bother.

Comment: "Differently"? What for? Because I tell you this is the way to go? Well... Anyway, you have the distribution of $(X,Z)$, how do you use it to write a formula for $E[Z;X\gt\gamma]$?

Comment: I believe you one hundred percent this is the way to go. I said differently meaning more detailed, if you can.

Comment: OK. "More detailed" starts with "a formula for E[Z;X>γ]".

Comment: I can write for the second conditional expectation $E[ Z|  X>γ]= ∫_γ^∞zf_ {Z|X} ( z|x)dx$. Hope that this is ok.

Comment: First, the formula is wrong (what is $z$?). Second, my suggestion was to give a formula for $E[Z;X\gt\gamma]$, not $E[Z\mid X\gt\gamma]$.

Comment: Ok, then $E[Z; X>γ]= ∫_γ^∞∫_{- ∞}^∞zf_{Z;X} (z;x)dz dx= ∫_γ^∞E[ Z|X=x] f_X (x)dx$.