# Expectation Conditioned on Other RV > Constant

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

I'm trying to confirm an answer I saw in another post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/506896/derivative-in-the-case-of-conditional-expectation) and prove that $ E[Z|X>\gamma]=∫_\gamma^\infty E[Z∣X=x]f_X(x)\text{d}x $ where $X$ and $Z$ are random variables with density functions $f_X$ and $f_Z$ respectively and $\gamma$ is a constant.

Unfortunately I keep getting an extra $\text{P}(X>\gamma)^{-1}$ factor on the right hand side: 
$ E[Z|X>\gamma]=\text{P}(X>\gamma)^{-1}∫_\gamma^\infty E[Z∣X=x]f_X(x)\text{d}x $

This extra factor comes from calculating $f_{Z|X>\gamma}$ = $\text{P}(X>\gamma)^{-1}\int_{\gamma}^{\infty} f_{X,Z}(x,z) \text{d}x$ .  Is this correct or is the original answer wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct and the other answer is correct, you are just not acquainted with the notation. $E(Z; A) $ is a notation for $E(Z1_A)$ which is equal to $E(Z|A)P(A).$

Comment: I see, thanks.  Does $E[Z,A]$ = $E[Z;A]$ as well or perhaps that was a typo in the post?

Comment: @ChadZ11 Not standard in my experience but I assume that's what the poster meant from context (i.e. their equation is right under that assumption).